# CallableStatement error: void cannot be dereferenced

Tags: java

I'm trying to call a stored procedure using CallableStament, but when I do call the method for it returns

> Error:(35, 62) java: void cannot be dereferenced.

Code:

```java
 public class Connect {

    public void connDB() throws Exception {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@test123:4321:test1", "test", "test")) {

            if (conn != null) {
                System.out.println("Connected to the database!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.format("SQL State: %s\n%s", e.getSQLState(), e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    public void callablestatement(int resync_value) {
        Connect conectivitateDb = new Connect();

        CallableStatement stmt = conectivitateDb.connDB().prepareCall("{call resync_entity.resync_this_entity( ?) }");

        stmt.setInt(1, resync_value);
        stmt.execute();
    }
}
```

If I do the callable statement in the try catch block in from the conndb method, it works just fine.

Comment: *If I do the callable statement in the try catch block in from the conndb method, it works just fine* : really `catch (Exception e) {

    }`

Comment: `connDB` returns `void` instead you probably should return `Connection` so you can actually call the `prepareCall` method.

Comment: Does the code even compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the `Connection` from your **`void`** method to chain the call like `conectivitateDb.connDB().prepareCall` - you would then have no way of **closing** that `Connection` so doing it like that would cause a definite connection leak. You should probably pass the `Connection` to your method instead, and be sure to at least print any exceptions you receive. Something like,

```
public void callablestatement(Connection conn, int resync_value) {
    String qry = "{call resync_entity.resync_this_entity(?)}";
    try (CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall(qry)) {
        stmt.setInt(1, resync_value);
        stmt.execute();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And don't forget to close your `Connection` from the caller.

Comment: I'm calling the procedure from an array, dosen't that mean that i don't have to close the connection manually?

Comment: @GabrielAlin You can probably wrap it with a try-with-resources, but you didn't post that code. The important thing is to close the connection.